# D3DX Vector Math function for projection?

Tags: c++, math, directx, direct3d, direct3d10

Is there a D3DX10 vector3 math function to calculate the projection of one D3DXVECTOR3 onto another?

Comment: Probably not, but you should be able to do this in a single line anyway.

Comment: @MaticOblak would you be able to show me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematically projecting vector a to vector b:
p = (a*(b/|b|))*(b/|b|)
As for the code I do not know even what language are you writing in. Anyway, the only difference may bi in using pointers or objects..

```
 D3DXVECTOR3 *a; //input
 D3DXVECTOR3 *b; //input
 D3DXVECTOR3 *tmpVec; //create new temporary vector I guess
 D3DXVec3Normalize(tmpVec, b); //tmpVec becomes normalized b vector
 D3DXVECTOR3 *p = tmpVec*D3DXVec3Dot(a, tmpVec); //result
```

I hope this helps..

Comment: How does the last line work? you cannot multiply pointers (it won't multiply the contents, just the pointers and crash soon)

Comment: sorry, as I said, I didn't even know what language to write in and couldn't try to debug. In c++ you can lose all the pointers and put "&" symbols before vectors in functions that require pointers.